# Using WP Multisite for multi language site? A good option?

Tags: multisite, multi-language

I´m going to develop a site for a client which requires multiple languages. I have no experience with this from beforehand so I´m researching what might be the best way to do this.

The webpage will be in swedish, english and norwegian. I must have the ability to have separate content in each language, like separate news posts for each language, or separate products etc.

Would using WP multisite be a good way to achieve this? I´m thinking I can do like this: 
Start a network with three sites: www.domain.se /en and /no. Develop for the first language version (swedish) and fill it with the correct content. Export the content, and import it from the other installations. Then replace the contents with the same content in the other languages.

Would this be a good way to achieve what I want, or would you suggest some other way?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the plugin [Multilingual Press](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multilingual-press/) for exact this setup: It helps to synchronize multiple sub sites in a multi-site installation.

Running an import and an export each time you publish or update a page is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that out. I would not run import/export each time the page updates though, since the point would be that their content would be handled independently once the major content is set.

I mean, most of the content on the sites are going to be identical, just i different languages. This like products, services etc. But things like "newsposts" must be independent, so that they are not forced to translate news that doesnt matter for other countries.